# Ruby threading vs normal

Tags: ruby, multithreading

Lets say I have 4 folders with 25 folders in each. In each of those 25 folders there is 20 folders each with 1 very long text document. The method i'm using now seems to have room to improve and in every scenario in which I implement ruby's threads, the result is slower than before. I have an array of the 54names of the folders. I iterate through each and use a foreach method to get the deeply nested files. In the foreach loop I do 3 things. I get the contents of today's file, I get the contents of yesterday's file, and I use my diff algorithm to find what has changed from yesterday to today. How would you do this faster with threads.

```
def backup_differ_loop device_name

  device_name.strip!
  Dir.foreach("X:/Backups/#{device_name}/#{@today}").each do |backup|

    if backup != "." and backup != ".."
      @today_filename = "X:/Backups/#{device_name}/#{@today}/#{backup}"
      @yesterday_filename = "X:/Backups/#{device_name}/#{@yesterday}/#{backup.gsub(@today, @yesterday)}"

      if File.exists?(@yesterday_filename)
        today_backup_content = File.open(@today_filename, "r").read
        yesterday_backup_content = File.open(@yesterday_filename, "r").read

        begin
         Diffy::Diff.new(yesterday_backup_content, today_backup_content, :include_plus_and_minus_in_html => true, :context => 1).to_s(:html)
        rescue
         #do nothing just continue
        end

        end

      else
       #file not found
      end

    end

  end
```

Comment: The simple version of threads would be to use a pool to process each file (or even directory/device, depending on scope) in a separate thread as a single standalone process. A pool avoids a little bit of overhead by allowing a single thread to (one-at-a-time) process multiple items. If there is no modified shared data (ie. "backup" is unique for every thread process) then there is no concurrency issues to worry about (other than starting it). Also, the version of Ruby matters as to if this may even be a beneficial change .. now go read and design an implementation. Come back with a problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of your logic is finding all files in a specific folder. Instead of doing Dir.foreach and then checking against "." and ".." you can do this in one line:

```
files = Dir.glob("X:/Backups/#{device_name}/#{@today}/*").select { |item| File.file?(item)}
```

Notice the `/*` at the end? This will search 1 level deep (inside the @today folder). If you want to search inside sub-folders too, replace it with `/**/*` so you'll get array of all files inside all sub-folders of @today.

So I'd first have a method which would give me a double array containing a bunch of arrays of matching files:

```
def get_matching_files
  matching_files = []

  Dir.glob("X:/Backups/#{device_name}/#{@today}/*").select { |item| File.file?(item)}.each do |backup|
    today_filename = File.absolute_path(backup) # should get you X:/Backups...converts to an absolute path
    yesterday_filename = "X:/Backups/#{device_name}/#{@yesterday}/#{backup.gsub(@today, @yesterday)}"

    if File.exists?(yesterday_filename)
      matching_files << [today_filename, yesterday_filename]
    end
  end

  return matching_files
end
```

and call it:

```
matching_files = get_matching_files
```

NOW we can start the multi-threading which is where things probably slow down. I'd first get all the files from the array matching_files into a queue, then start 5 threads which will go until the queue is empty:

```
queue = Queue.new
matching_files.each { |file| queue << file }

# 5 being the number of threads
5.times.map do
  Thread.new do
    until queue.empty?
      begin
        today_file_content, yesterday_file_content = queue.pop
        Diffy::Diff.new(yesterday_backup_content, today_backup_content, :include_plus_and_minus_in_html => true, :context => 1).to_s(:html)
      rescue
        #do nothing just continue
      end
    end
  end
end.each(&:join)
```

I can't guarantee my code will work because I don't have the entire context of your program. I hope I've given you some ideas.

And the MOST important thing: The standard implementation of Ruby can run only 1 thread at a time. This means even if you implement the code above, you won't get a significant performance difference. So get Rubinius or JRuby which allow more than 1 threads to be running at a time. Or if you prefer to use the standard MRI Ruby, then you'll need to re-structure your code (you can keep your original version) and start multiple processes. You'll just need something like a shared database where you can store the matching_files (as a single row, for example) and every time a process will 'take' something from that database, it will mark that row as 'used'. SQLite is a good db for this I think because it's thread safe by default.

Comment: Each file will have 2 different file_contents. So when you are looping and creating threads, where are you getting the content and how are you determining which one is todays and yesterdays if your using a queue?

Comment: You're first pairing them in an array so you get a double array with a bunch of those pairs. The queue is the double array itself, each queue.pop will get a single array element with 2 items in it, thus the parallel assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Most Ruby implementations don't have "true" multicore threading i.e. threads won't gain you any performance improvement since the interpreter can only run one thread at a time. For applications like yours with lots of disk IO this is especially true.  In fact, even with real multithreading your applications might be IO-bound and still not see much of an improvement.

You are more likely to get results by finding some inefficient algorithm in your code and improving it.